# about special character handling

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, logic

I have written a program there is a point where I convert' /n' to '' tags like below( that mean if the user gives input as a sentence into two lines this will convert into '
' between two lines as when it is print HTML writer will recognize this and print that line into two lines)

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataValue))
                        {
                            if (dataValue.Contains("\r\n"))
                            {
                                dataValue = dataValue.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
                            }

                            if (dataValue.Contains("\n"))
                            {
                                dataValue = dataValue.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
                            }
                        }

                        table.Add("<%" + data.TagName + "%>", dataValue);
```

after few days, according to requirement, I needed to handle special characters because when we are printing this into word .doc using HTML writer if there is like '<,>' or any HTML tags, this is stopping the writing doc from that point as it is considering as HTML tag.so as a solution I came up like this

```
string character = (string)table[tag];
                    character = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(character);
                    subject = subject.Replace(tag, character);
                    body = body.Replace(tag, character);
```

where I'm going to encode the HTML tags then it continues printing, but the result of this case the part 1 wrong gone,   as an example in part one its convert line break to '' and when it's print it prints as a line break for the paragraph but now because of the new solution it encodes and it prints as '' tag ..how to come with a solution here.

Comment: I think we need to see the actual results of the replacements. It's hard to tell from the question. "as example in part one its convert line break to..." ??

Comment: Input :      line one : test test    line two: test 2    this will print as it is if there is no HTML encoding, but bcz of encoding this is print as testtest</br>test2

Comment: You mean when you have `\r\n` n the data, you want it be converted to `<br/>` for HTML display but remains as `\r\n` while printing to word document?

Comment: How are you displaying the data in the HTML? As a table? As a paragraph? As a list? Can you share that code in the original question please?